# how to save a subimage in Rust?

Tags: rust

I got a subimage from an image in Rust. Though the document seems to list no way to save a subimage conveniently. Do I have to read each pixel to write to a buffer?

[Here follows my code in Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0c75383117c19fdd6a6bd5e7db397b0a)

```
fn main() {
    
    f();
}
fn f(){
let (w,h)=(100,100);
for (x,y) in &[(100 as u32,200 as u32)]{
         let mut img = image::open("mySvg.png").unwrap();
         let subimg = imageops::crop(&mut img, *x , *y , w , h );
         let mut output = std::fs::File::create(format!("mySvg.{}.{}.png",x,y).as_str()).unwrap();
         subimg.write_to(&mut output, ImageFormat::Png).unwrap(); //Error!!
}}
```

```
 no method named `write_to` found for struct `SubImage<&mut DynamicImage>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:12:17
   |
12 |          subimg.write_to(&mut output, ImageFormat::Png).unwrap(); //Error!!
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `SubImage<&mut DynamicImage>`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method [`write_to`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.write_to) is not implemented for [`SubImage`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/struct.SubImage.html).

However, the method [`SubImage::to_image`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/struct.SubImage.html#method.to_image) is available, which returns an [`ImageBuffer`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html).

One can then use [`ImageBuffer::save_with_format`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.save_with_format) to write out the file.

I've used an [image of Ferris](https://www.rustacean.net/) and the following directory structure:

```
.  stackoverflow_save_subimage
├─ Cargo.lock
├─ Cargo.toml
├─ ferris.png
├─ src/
│  └─ main.rs
└─ target/
```

```rust
use image::*;

fn main() {
    let (w, h) = (100, 100);

    for &(x, y) in &[(100, 200)] {
        let mut img = image::open("ferris.png").unwrap();
        let sub_img = imageops::crop(&mut img, x, y, w, h);
        let path = format!("ferris_crop.{}.{}.png", x, y);
        sub_img
            .to_image()
            .save_with_format(&path, ImageFormat::Png)
            .unwrap();
    }
}
```

Running the above generates the following cropped `ferris_crop.100.200.png`:

[image: The cropped output of ferris.png]